# Separate env.php files for Google App Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, development-environment, google-apps, production-environment

I was wondering if anyone has figured out how to have a production env.php and a development env.php. Since Deploying your app just takes whatever code is in the directory you specify and throws it into a version, I can't figure out how this is possible.

I would have to copy my production env.php file over my local one every time I wanted to deploy something.

If there is someway that I can use the Source Code on the cloud as the production code, that would be helpful. I know how to ignore an env.php file through git. I don't see a way to do this, however, which really makes no sense to me. Why have the source code on there if you can't use it in production?

Comment: I do not have experience with Google App Engine, but usually this is achieved by including different files depending on hostname or some other environmental value.

Comment: @syck Yes, but I think it's better practice to have separate files.

Comment: You can have different files. The one you include when you can prove that you are running on your development machine and the other everytime else.

Comment: Yeah. I'll probably have to end up doing that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way.

The appcfg.py command allows to to override environment variables at deploy time.

-- update with open source tool to manage environments --

We've written a deployment tool to automatically build the deploy command with live environment variable overrides.

And we've open-sourced it today!

https://github.com/Venditan/appengine-deploy

-- update with example --

Suppose we have these environment variables defined in our app.yaml file:

```
env_variables:
  DB_HOST: localhost
  DB_USER: marty
```

This works great for local development.

But then, when we deploy to live, we want them to be different:

```
appcfg.py update app.yaml -E DB_HOST:"1.2.3.4" -E DB_USER:"emmett"
```

tada!

Comment: Can you update your answer to include a sample of how to override the variables using appcfg.py?

Comment: Sure - give me an hour or two to get back to a laptop and I'll update the ticket.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I don't see them mentioning that in the documentation.

Comment: Hey, no worries! I might look at making our deployment environment manager Open Source too.

Comment: let me know if you do. =)

Comment: Hey there - here you go! we've open-sourced it today! https://github.com/Venditan/appengine-deploy